# Vim key mappings in insert mode

Tags: vim

I have edited my `.vimrc` file and mapped some commands. They are only working in normal mode. Is there any way to map commands in insert mode? (e.g. commands involved with special keys such as Ctrl) For example, can I copy in insert mode using Ctrl+c?

Comment: What do you want to copy in insert mode using Ctrl+c?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first letter in the `:map` commands determines which modes (`:h map-modes`) they apply to. So `:nnoremap` is for `n`ormal mode, and `:inoremap` for insert mode.

You usually cant' just use the same *right-hand side*; you need to consider that you're in a different mode. To invoke a (normal mode) command from insert mode:

- prepend `<Esc>` if you want to stay in normal mode after the mapping
- prepend `<C-o>` if you want to continue in insert mode after the mapping; this command switches to normal mode for *just one command*

For example, to map `:w` to `<C-s>`, you'd use this: `:nnoremap <C-s> :w<CR>`. The corresponding insert mode mapping (staying there) is:

```
:inoremap <C-s> <C-o>:w<CR
```

Comment: For example, example `inoremap jk <ESC>` is that: when you are in the insert mode, once you press `j` and `k`, then vim executes `<ESC>` for you.

Answer (score 4):

See `:help imap`. You can map keys, including keys with control, to various things within insert mode. For instance, if you wanted to copy the current word in insert mode with Ctrl+c you could use

```
inoremap <C-c> <esc>yiwea
```